# Sum of first nth term of series

Tags: ruby

I am not understanding why my code isn't looping, for any input I give I get the result of `"1.00"`

I feel like I am being silly and missing something very obvious.

This series is shown in other places most often as **1/3n+1**

But if `series_sum(1) = "1.00"`

then **3+1 = 4** giving you **1/4** to add to your sum for input of **1** which doesn't make sense

```
def series_sum(n)
  sum = 0
  if n == 0
    return "0.00"
  else
    for i in 1..n 
      sum += 1/(1+(3*(i-1)))
    end
  end

  return "%.2f" % sum.to_s

end
```

for `series_sum(1)` should be `"1.00"`
`series_sum(2)` should be `"1.25"`
`series_sum(3)` should be `"1.39"`
etc

My code gives `"1.00"` for any input

Why won't this code run the loop and perform the sum?

Comment: When dividing, if the numerator or denominator is a float, the result will be a float; else it will be an integer (with the remainder being discarded). Integer division: `4/2 #=> 2; 4/3 #=> 1; 1/2 #=> 0`. Float division `4/3.0 #=> 1.33...; 1.0/2 #=> 0.5; 1.to_f/2 #=> 0.5`. A more complex example: `3/(2/(1+4).to_f) = 3/(2/5.0) = 3/0.4 #=> 7.5`.  You can alternatively write `1.fdiv(3) #=> 0.5`. See [Numeric#fdiv](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Numeric.html#method-i-fdiv).

Comment: Float division, could also be fixed changing this line: `sum += 1.0/(1+(3*(i-1)))`. Note the numerator: `1.0`. Side note, instead of `for` loop, use a more Rubyish: `(1..n).each do |i|`

Answer (score 2):

When you have expression like `z = x/y`, in ruby it does specify type for output based on operand provided for division. If `x` & `y` both are integer, output calculated is also integer and float value is removed.

So to obtain output as `float`, you need to have one operand at least as float value which can be found using `to_f` on variable. Here you need to change only,

```
- sum += 1/(1+(3*(i-1)))
+ sum += 1.0/(1+(3*(i-1)))
```